# How to limit check box clicked using Angular.js/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have many check boxes in a loop and I need to restrict those using some condition using Angular.js. Let me share [my code in Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/N06ozqIZEeKigYGTcEUa?p=preview) first.

I can check there each day has one check box and if user is clicking on `+` button the check box is increasing. Here I need when user has checked on max `2` check box from any day the other will get disabled.

Only 2 checkbox can checked from that whole table from the `7` days. I also need after clicking on `store` button the two check box value with respective row drop down data should fetch into controller side function.

Comment: Bind the value of each checkbox to a model (using the `ng-model` directive) and use `$scope.$watch` function to monitor the count of the number of checkboxes selected and, based on that count, enable or disable the desired elements.

Comment: Can you edit your answer there .In plunkr.

Comment: This question is not self-contained, so should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the other answer gets you on the right track, and this one should get you all the way there. You basically want to take advantage of angular's `ng-disabled` attribute, and when the expression you give it evaluates to `true`, the form field it's attached to will be disabled.

In your html, you can put the following on any form field you would like disabled when your criteria are met:

```
  ng-disabled="isDisabled($parent.$index, $index)"
```

The parent index will refer to the day of the current outer loop, and the index refers to the current answer in the inner loop.

The main controller logic I used to implement this solution is the following:

```
  // initialize an array of selections
  $scope.selectedAnswers = [];

  // check if answer is selected...
  // have to keep track of both the index of the answer and its parent day
  $scope.answerIsSelected = function(dayIdx, answerIdx) {
    var thisAnswer = $scope.days[dayIdx].answers[answerIdx];
    return $scope.selectedAnswers.indexOf(thisAnswer) > -1;
  };

  // depending on whether answer is already selected, 
  // adds it to or splices it from the selectedAnswers array
  $scope.toggleAnswerSelected = function(dayIdx, answerIdx) {
    var thisAnswer = $scope.days[dayIdx].answers[answerIdx];
    if ($scope.answerIsSelected(dayIdx, answerIdx)) {
      $scope.selectedAnswers.splice($scope.selectedAnswers.indexOf(thisAnswer), 1);
    } else {
      $scope.selectedAnswers.push(thisAnswer);
    }
  };

  // the check on each form element to see if should be disabled
  // returns true if the answer is not an element in the selected array
  // and if there are already two answers in the array
  $scope.isDisabled = function(dayIdx, answerIdx) {
    return !$scope.answerIsSelected(dayIdx, answerIdx) && $scope.selectedAnswers.length === 2;
  };
```

And finally, the attributes you want on your checkbox at the end of the row:

```
  <input type="checkbox" 
         name="chk" 
         value="true" 
         ng-checked="answerIsSelected($parent.$index, $index)"
         ng-click="toggleAnswerSelected($parent.$index, $index)"
         ng-disabled="isDisabled($parent.$index, $index)">
```

Full snippet below...

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$q, $filter) {

  $scope.submitted = false;
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.days = [];

    $scope.listOfCategory = [{
      id:1,
      name: 'Category 1',
      value: 1
    }, {
      id:2,
      name: 'Category 2',
      value: 2
    },{
  id:3,
  name: 'Category 3',
        value: 3
 }];

     $scope.listOfSubCategory=[];

    //emulating ajax response: this should be removed, days reponse
    var response = {
      data: [{
        day_name: "Monday"
      }, {
        day_name: "Tuesday"
      }, {
        day_name: "Wednesday"
      }, {
        day_name: "Thursday"
      }, {
        day_name: "Friday"
      }, {
        day_name: "Saturday",
      }, {
        day_name: "Sunday"
      }]
    };
    //end response

    //success
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj) {
      obj.answers = [];
      $scope.addNewRow(obj.answers);
      $scope.days.push(obj);
    });
  };
  
  $scope.renderWithMode = function(index,catvalue,parent,isEditMode){
    if(isEditMode){
      $scope.removeBorder(index,catvalue,parent);
    }
  };
  
  $scope.removeBorder = function(index,catvalue,parent){
    //make $http call here
    //below code should be removed, its emulated response
    var subcategories = [{
        id:1,
        name: 'SubCategory 1',
        value: 1
      }, {
        id:2,
        name: 'SubCategory 2',
        value: 2
      }, {
        id:3,
        name: 'SubCategory 3',
        value: 3
      }, {
        id:4,
        name: 'SubCategory 4',
        value: 4
      }];
     
    //after reponse from server as subcaegory  
    if(!$scope.listOfSubCategory[parent]){
      $scope.listOfSubCategory[parent] = [];  
    }
 //console.log('value',catvalue);
  var subcategories1=[];
   // $scope.listOfSubCategory[parent][index] = angular.copy(subcategories);
   var result = $filter('filter')(subcategories, {id:catvalue})[0];
  // console.log('result',result);
   subcategories1.push(result)
   $scope.listOfSubCategory[parent][index] = subcategories1;
  };

  $scope.addNewRow = function(answers) {
    answers.push({
      category: null,
      subcategory: null,
      comment: null
    });
  };
  
  $scope.submitAnswers = function(){
    // console.log($scope.selectedAnswers);
    $scope.submitted = true;
    $scope.sendToServer = $scope.selectedAnswers;
  };
  
  $scope.getResponse = function(){
    //emulating reponse: this should come from server,
    var response = {
      data: [{
        day_name: "Monday",
        answers:[{
          category:2,
          subcategory:1,
          comment:'This is answer 1'
        },{
          category:1,
          subcategory:2,
          comment:'This is answer 2'
        }]
      }, {
        day_name: "Tuesday",
        answers:[{
          category:1,
          subcategory:2,
          comment:'This is answer 1'
        }]
      }, {
        day_name: "Wednesday"
      }, {
        day_name: "Thursday"
      }, {
        day_name: "Friday"
      }, {
        day_name: "Saturday",
      }, {
        day_name: "Sunday"
      }]
    };
    
    $scope.days = [];
    angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj) {
      if(!obj.answers){
        obj.answers = [{
          category:null,
          subcategory:null,
          comment:null
        }];
      }
      $scope.days.push(obj);
    });
    
    $scope.isEditMode = true;
  };
  
  $scope.selectedAnswers = [];
  
  $scope.answerIsSelected = function(dayIdx, answerIdx) {
    var thisAnswer = $scope.days[dayIdx].answers[answerIdx];
    return $scope.selectedAnswers.indexOf(thisAnswer) > -1;
  };
  
  $scope.toggleAnswerSelected = function(dayIdx, answerIdx) {
    var thisAnswer = $scope.days[dayIdx].answers[answerIdx];
    if ($scope.answerIsSelected(dayIdx, answerIdx)) {
      $scope.selectedAnswers.splice($scope.selectedAnswers.indexOf(thisAnswer), 1);
    } else {
      $scope.selectedAnswers.push(thisAnswer);
    }
  };
  
  $scope.isDisabled = function(dayIdx, answerIdx) {
    return !$scope.answerIsSelected(dayIdx, answerIdx) && $scope.selectedAnswers.length === 2;
  };
  
  $scope.removeRow = function(answers,index,parent){
    answers.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.listOfSubCategory[parent].splice(index,1);
   // answers.splice(answers.length-1,1);
  };
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Plunker
  <table ng-init="init()" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Sub Subcategory</th>
        <th>Comments Or special promotion</th>
        <th>Add More</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="detailsstockid">
      <tr ng-repeat="d in days track by $index">
        <td>{{d.day_name}}</td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers track by $index">
                <td>
                  <select class="form-control" 
                          id="answer_{{$index}}_category" 
                          name="answer_{{$index}}_category"
                          ng-model="answer.category"
                          ng-options="cat.name for cat in listOfCategory track by cat.value"
                          ng-init="renderWithMode($index,answer.category.value,$parent.$index,isEditMode)" 
                          ng-change="removeBorder($index,answer.category.value,$parent.$index)">
                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers track by $index">
                <td>
                  <select class="form-control" 
                          id="answer_{{$index}}_subcategory" 
                          name="answer_{{$index}}_subcategory" 
                          ng-model="answer.subcategory" 
                          ng-options="sub.name for sub in listOfSubCategory[$parent.$index][$index]">
                    <option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
                <td>
                  <input type="text" 
                         id="answer_{{$index}}_comment" 
                         name="answer_{{$index}}_comment" 
                         placeholder="Add Comment" 
                         ng-model="answer.comment" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers track by $index">
                <td style="width:20px">
                  <input ng-show="d.answers.length>1" 
                         class="btn btn-red"   
                         type="button" 
                         name="minus" 
                         id="minus" 
                         value="-" 
                         style="width:20px; text-align:center;" 
                         ng-click="removeRow(d.answers, $index,$parent.$index)" /> 
                </td>
                <td ng-show="$last">
                  <input type="button" 
                         class="btn btn-success"
                         name="plus" 
                         id="plus" 
                         value="+"
                         style="width:20px; text-align:center;" 
                         ng-click="addNewRow(d.answers)" />
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" 
                       name="chk" 
                       value="true" 
                       ng-checked="answerIsSelected($parent.$index, $index)"
                       ng-click="toggleAnswerSelected($parent.$index, $index)"
                       ng-disabled="isDisabled($parent.$index, $index)" /> 
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" 
         ng-click="submitAnswers()" 
         value="Store">
  <pre ng-if="submitted"> {{ sendToServer | json }} </pre>
 <!-- <input type="button" value="Edit" ng-click="getResponse()">-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I checked your answer,i need to disable only check box not other field and also retrieve the checked value with respective row all value.

Comment: All you had to do to disable only the checkboxes was to remove the `ng-disabled` attribute from all the other inputs/selects, but I went back in and edited them out accordingly. And when you click `Store`, the `pre` displays the selected values for each of the selected answer rows. Does this not answer your question?

Comment: yes,i need only disable the check box after 2 checked.After editing please give the comment.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, but this is turning from "question" to "do my homework for free", deleting my answer and voting for close this right now.

Comment: @BennettAdams : Your code is working properly and so flexible.Thanks.

Comment: @BennettAdams : Can this disable for a particular day only ?Means for a particular day one can check two check box not more than that.

Comment: @satya, yes, it would require some minor tweaks in the `isDisabled` logic to accomplish that. In my answer I have given you the explanation and the tools in angular to do so. But as @coma said, this is not meant to be a bespoke-code-solutions-for-free service. I will leave it to you to go the last mile. Cheers.

Comment: @BennettAdams : Dont worry i have already solved that problem.Thank you again.